# MVC 4 intranet template using windows authorization - Roles does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

With Windows 2012 server and VS2012, I create a new MVC 4 project using the Intranet template for windows authentication. I publish it to the Windows 2012 server. Bang, everything works and I can peruse the site. So I add the following to the HomeController:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\GROUP")]
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
...
}
```

Authentication still works, but I'm immediately given the error page with the Big red: "Error. An error occurred while processing your request."

I try domain local groups, global groups, full path to group nothing works. Then I try

```
[Authorize(Users = @"DOMAIN\ME")]
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
...
}
```

That works! But I want to use windows groups. Everything I've read says it works just use Roles = ..., But for some reason, I'm missing something. From the basic template I haven't changed a thing, just added the [Authorize(Roles = "..."].

I've searched for hours on Google and ended up mostly here on stackoverflow. What am I missing? Its got to be something simple.

If it helps... the server is my own development server and I have windows authentication and authorization working on it in other projects WCF and ASP.NET Forms websites.

New development: It appear that for roles, the server is trying to access roles membership based on the SqlRoleProvider

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'CS\CS446$'.]
...
System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +1466
System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +12322757
System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +149
System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +265
...
```

It does authenticate me using windows, and appears to authorize me via windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

The above symptoms pointed me back to the server configuration where I actually found the problem.

**Conditions:** This is an application within the default site where the default membership provider is configured as the AspNetSqlRoleProvider. Your .NET Roles in the application inherit their settings from the Default Web Site (or whatever parent web site you use).

[image: Under .NET Roles for your application, Click Set Default Provider...]

Apparently the Intranet Template for MVC 4.5 does not include a setting for this and accepts the inherited setting for roles, but correctly checks the users in the active directory (i.e. I do have a user in the database that doesn't work but the windows user does as noted in the original question).

**Solution:**
In Web.config, I added the following lines to enable AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider as the default and remove the AspNetSqlRoleProvider:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

The  section appears to be optional as I first got it working with just the following:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
```

I hope this helps some other frustrated soul. A hat tip goes to Trey for making me think about going back to the IIS configuration where I found the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Funny to stuble on this right when I am implementing myself.  I think you are doing it right, might just be a bad GROUP you are testing.

This works for me:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\Domain Users")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Here the important part of my Web.config for good measure.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

#### UPDATE

Make sure your connectionStrings use SQL Logins and SQL is setup for mixed mode, if not you have to go back through the setup and change it.  Took three days to figure out a developer had not selected mixed mode when they installed on their dev box once.  I feel you pain on this issue.

Comment: Maybe not related but we did have a loopback problem when we setup our dev environment because our dev boxes have so many sites on them we use host headers.  This fixed it: http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2325

Comment: Web.config is the same except for the <idenity impersonate="true" /> but that didn't fix it. I don't use host headers... so unlikely but you made me think of something else, I'm working on it again this morning and will report back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, The SQL errors that I have above are a symptom of the fact that I embed the connection string in the web.config of the application **apparently** rendering it useless to child applications (not sure why actually, but it isn't listed in sub-site connection string lists). A nice side effect when you have students using a main site, but you don't want them playing with your other projects. But to your original observation, it is in mixed mode. Thanks for your quick responses! I solved it and detailed my solution above (or below as the case may be).